# How to create one stream listening to multiple Firestore documents created from list of documents references in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to create one stream, that is using multiple documents references that are stored and fetched from Firebase Firestore.

Lets say I have two collection named `users` and `documents`. When user is created he gets document with his `id` in `users` collection with field named `documentsHasAccessTo` that is list of references to documents inside `documents` collection. It is important, that these documents can be located in different sub collections inside `documents` collection so I dont want to query whole `documents` and filter it, in order to save Firestore transfer and make it faster I already know paths to `documents` stored in `documentsHasAccessTo` field.

So for example, I can have user with data inside `users/<user uid>` document with `documentsHasAccessTo` field that stores 3 different document references.

I would like to achieve something like this (untested):

```dart
final userId = 'blablakfn1n21n4109';
final usersDocumentRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$userId');
usersDocumentRef.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
    final references = snapshot.data()['documentsHasAccessTo'] as List<DocumentReference>;

    final documentsStream =  // create single query stream using all references from list
});
```

Keep in mind, that it would also be great, if this stream would update query if `documentsHasAccessTo` changes like in the example above, hence I used `snapshots()` on `usersDocumentReferences` rather than single `get()` fetch.

The more I think about this Im starting to believe this is simple impossible or theres a more simple and clean solution. Im open to anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rxdart`'s `switchMap` and `MergeStream`:

```
usersDocumentRef.snapshots().switchMap((snapshot) {
  final references = snapshot.data()['documentsHasAccessTo'] as List<DocumentReference>;
  return MergeStream(references.map(ref) => /* do something that creates a stream */));
});
```

Comment: It looks like its time to learn RxDart

Comment: You won't regret it :)